# How to use Google Drive iOS Sample

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

Can someone let me know how to build below sample?

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FDriveSample

Instructions says it will build along with GTL.framework but how to build/run DriveSample?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate google drive through google drive api for ios.
you can follow following url to integrate google drive "https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart"
Use this command to anonymously check out the latest project source code:

## you can check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.

svn checkout http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-api-objectivec-client-read-only